# Zurb Foundation Top Bar & jQuery - check if mobile navigation is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

How can I check with jQuery or JavaScript, if Foundation's top bar mobile Navigation (dropdown) is currently active?

I'd like to check it when resizing a window. In the moment when it switches to mobile and back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('nav[role=navigation]').find('section li.has-dropdown li').hasClass('active')
```

You choose the **nav** tag which has the attribute **role** to **navigation**. Inside this, take all the **children li** which have the class **active** and which are contain in the **li** with the **class has-dropdown**

Comment: Edit answer with explanations